# What does the prefix :: mean

Tags: clojure

I have seen the following prefix `::` what does it represent? A `:abc` is a keyword, but what is `::abc` ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 14):

Suppose that the current namespace is `my.app`. Then, `::x` is a reader shorthand for `:my.app/x`, a keyword whose namespace part is `my.app` and name is `x`.

Comment: Additionally, `::bar/baz` might expand to `:foo.bar/baz` if you added a corresponding namespace alias, eg. with `:as` in a `require` clause.

Answer (score 1):

In other languages this is the default namespace. But not sure if this exists in Clojure too. Refering to [this comment](http://travis-whitton.blogspot.de/2009/10/clojure-syntax.html?showComment=1259353875871#c688885964051363028), it seems to be correct.